# Which continuous effect happens if they enter at the same time

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I play a [Warp World](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWarp%20World%5d) and reveal a [Null profusion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNull%20profusion%5d) and a [Price of knowledge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPrice%20of%20knowledge%5d), what is my handsize? The gatherer rules for Warp World state that revealed cards enter at the same time, so their time stamps are the same. So my question is which one goes first and what is my hand size then?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you're casting Warp World on your turn—since it *is* a sorcery—you get to choose which order the effects apply. If someone else cast the Warp World on their turn or you used something like [Quicken](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bQuicken%5d) to cast it on someone else's turn, the person whose turn it is would get to choose.

> 613.6j If two or more objects would receive a timestamp simultaneously, such as by entering a zone simultaneously or becoming attached simultaneously, the active player determines their relative timestamp order at that time.

Comment: Who is the active player if the turn player is dead? Say the above enchantments are exiled by [mtg:Banishing Light] under the active player's control and they lose the game. The Banishing Lights will be removed at the same time and the enchantments will come back at the same time. I can post it as a new question if needs be.

Comment: @ProgenitorMimic I would think that even though that player left the game it is still that player's turn at that moment so he is still the active player so the dead player decides.

Comment: @IvoBeckers i thought that dead players were not allowed to interfere with a match so they can't make desicions

Comment: @ProgenitorMimic you should ask it as a new question it is very interesting

Comment: @ProgenitorMimic I asked the question on another forum and there a lvl 2 judge says that the next player in turn order gets to decide it but he also says that it's technically not in the rules (yet): http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/magic-fundamentals/magic-rulings/773738-who-decides-when-there-is-no-active-player

Answer (score 1):

This is an update to the answer.

The controller chooses the timestamp order. If no controller, then the owner chooses. This is done in APNAP order.

Example: All players control 2 creature cards each. Then all creatures are exiled simultaneously. All players in APNAP order would choose the timestamp order for the cards they own put into exile this way.

613.7m: If two or more objects would receive a timestamp simultaneously, such as by entering a zone simultaneously or becoming attached simultaneously, their relative timestamps are determined in APNAP order (see rule 101.4). Objects controlled by the active player (or owned by the active player, if they have no controller) have an earlier relative timestamp in the order of that player's choice, followed by each other player in turn order.

Comment: For reference, this rule was changed in the [Ikoria rules update](https://web.archive.org/web/20221008015200/https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/news/comprehensive-rules-changes-2020-04-10) in 2020. It was rule 613.7k at the time.